# Are all of the major enemies in Gambit/Prime considered Bosses?

Tags: destiny-2

As in:

- Blockers
- Primeval
- High-Value Targets

Are any of these "boss" type enemies considered actually bosses? Or do they fall under the Major category?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the wiki](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Enemies); Blockers are Elite tier enemies, high-value targets are Majors and the Primeval itself is a boss/ultra. The Envoys should also be considered Majors.

Comment: What do Elite tier enemies fall under for spec mods? Boss spec? Major spec?

Comment: Elite and Major should be the same-ish tier. If it has an orange/yellow health bar, and no skull by the name it is affected by major spec. The skull indicates the enemy is a boss.

Comment: So ideally, I should be running major spec on gear, and swap out to boss spec for primeval damage phases, since according to you major spec will cover blockers and envoys

Comment: I don't have the gambit experience to really say whats most optimal. Taking time out to switch mods mid round is not great though. Either put boss spec on both special/heavy weapons or do 1 major spec 1 boss spec. The damage boost is reported to be only 7-8% though, so backup mag is another option to get extra shots before needing a reload.

Comment: The only boss in Gambit/Gambit Prime will be the primeval. Every other yellow health enemy will take extra damage from your 'major spec' mods. You probably want boss on heavy or special gear, swapping mods mid-game is inefficient and swapping guns will reduce ammo.